# How to save a very long string in SQlite (sqlite3 python)?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a long string that I want to save into a SQlite database (using the sqlite3 module with Python 3.5). It works fine until the string gets to roughly 500,000 characters. If it gets longer than it fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "SomeWord": syntax error
```

My code:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE data SET raw_str='{}' WHERE id=1".format(long_string))
connection.commit()
```

My string is a raw data string of a length of about 6 Mil. Even so, I expect to work with bigger data (10 to 100 times larger).

Comment: Assuming that by "raw data" you mean it's binary, sounds like you need a `BLOB`.

Comment: it's a list of strings that I made into json: long_string = json.dumps(["...", "...", ...])

Comment: I would not refer to JSON as "raw data." It's formatted or structured or something like that data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce your error message as follows. Note that `long_string` ends up with a single-quote character in it.

```
import json, sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('tmp.sqlite3')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("create table data (raw_str STRING, id INT)")
long_string = json.dumps(["' SomeWord"])
cursor.execute("Update data SET raw_str='{}' where id=1".format(long_string))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "SomeWord": syntax error

cursor.execute("Update data SET raw_str=? where id=1", [long_string])
# works
```

You should not use `str.format` to substitute string data into an SQL query. What seems to have happened is that your data contained a single-quote character, and so you have accidentally carried out an SQL injection attack on yourself.

Lucky for you the string didn't contain `'; drop table data; --`.

Comment: That was the issue with my data. My biggest instance so far turned out to be a list of about 133,000 elements with a combined length of about 150 Mil. Characters (ca. 150 MB as a txt-file). If I create a new row in my database with all the data in one collum I get: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" (SQL Access) or "BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe" (sqlite3 and print).